# What's a good color picking webapp?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for a decent color picking webapp. Hopefully it's not something that's bloated like a full fledged image editor or color scheme generator.

It should support hex values, and allow you to choose a color with a visual interface.

Answer (score 10):

I have 2, to recommend; these recommendations came to me from a successful designer and user experience expert.

- http://www.colourlovers.com/

  > ... a creative community where people from around the world create
  > and share colors, palettes and patterns, discuss the latest trends and explore colorful
  > articles... All in the spirit of love.

and

- http://kuler.adobe.com/

  > ... discover Adobe® Kuler™ — the web-hosted application for generating color themes that can inspire any project. No matter what you're creating, with Kuler you can experiment quickly with color variations and browse thousands of themes from the Kuler community.

I have used *kuler* myself and enjoyed what it outputs and how it works.

Comment: Kuler is the best.. because you have a set of five and you can use thema as a theme :D

Answer (score 5):

Helps you pick sets of colors:

http://colorschemedesigner.com

Answer (score 1):

Can you get much simpler than [ColorPicker.com](http://www.colorpicker.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

I've also had some luck with [kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/). Another site I've bookmarked, but never done much with, is http://www.colorotate.org/

Answer (score 0):

This is one of my favorites: [Name that color](http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color/). Very simple and effective, i've used it heaps.

Answer (score 0):

a very simple one I use often:
http://html-color-codes.info

Answer (score 0):

**[Colr.org](http://www.colr.org/)**

Instead of the usual 'here's a random selection of mixed color puke on a pallet, you can upload an image and it dynamically generates the pallet if colors from the image and floats them on top.

It also has other options like scraping a webpage for a color pallet.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:http://www.colourlovers.com/copaso/ColorPaletteSoftware

Answer (score 0):

I like Visibone - http://www.visibone.com/colorlab

Lost my boomarks in a recent update, or I'd link to the color switcher app I found several years back.

Answer (score 0):

[Colour Schemer](http://www.colorschemer.com/online.html) is a simple to use and provides a range of colours.